# How does Angular2+ ngFor directive iterate over the ref iterable?

Tags: angular, loops, ngfor, angular2-changedetection

I try to understand how the `*ngFor` directive of Angular works behind the scene.
Something I wanted to know was if the iterable passed to the directive was interpreted at each loop iteration (like the condition of the JS `for` loop) or if angular creates a "cache"-like variable with that value. To answer this question, I did a `ngFor` that has a method returning an array as the iterable object.

```
<li *ngFor="let data of test(dataArr)">{{data}}</li>
```

The related TS :

```
 dataArr = [1,2,3,4];
 iterationNb = 1;
 test(arr) {
    console.log('has iterated', this.iterationNb++);
    return arr.filter(i => true);
 }
```

And here what I get in the console :

```
has iterated 1
has iterated 2
has iterated 3
has iterated 4
```

If you need the angular project, here is my example app used for my tryouts : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kmyyw

That's great, I see that angular just call the method at each iteration. But that's where it starts to be complex for me...

I then tried to change the ref array `dataArr` used by the method by adding some other values in it like :

```
dataArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

But now I still have in my console 4 iterations...
Then I tried with

```
dataArr = [1,2];
```

and booom still 4 iterations...

So now I'm very confused about this...
Why do I have always 4 iteration ? The first attempt was just luck of having choosen 4 items in my array and in fact it has nothing to do with that ?
I tried to look at the angular ngfor source code but I'm still not that ninja that understands it without explanations...

Thanks

Comment: I tried with your stackblitz, it showed more than 4 iterations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That's great, I see that angular just call the method at each iteration. But that's where it starts to be complex for me...

You are not seeing iterations. Angular called the method each time the DOM was rendered. It has nothing to do with how many elements were in the array. It was just by luck you saw it count to 4.

```
<li *ngFor="let data of test(dataArr)">
```

The above is executed once per rendering pass. The `*ngFor` directive breaks down the expression into two variables. A reference to the *current* iterable, and a reference to the source *iterator*.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators

ngFor only needs to assign the source *iterator* once per rendering pass. In your expression the `test()` function returns the iterator (which happens to be an array). It will take the *next()* value from the iterator and assign it to the `data` variable which will be exposed in the template.

ngFor will keep calling *next()* until it reaches the end of the iterator. For each iteration ngFor checks if there is a DOM element that should be inserted, updated or removed. It knows what data goes with which DOM element using a *trackBy* function.

https://medium.com/@ramy_ali/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878

Comment: You can see that the method is called just once when the view is updated in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bansfo), where automatic change detection is turned off, and manual change detection is triggered every 4 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please also explain why there is the need for 4 rendering as you said `once per rendering pass` and from my comprehension there is just 1 rendering if the digest cycle has not noticed some changes. Tx

Comment: @ylerjen everytime a *zone* detects an async event in the web browser it triggers Angular change detection. The default behavior for components is "CheckAlways" which means that Angular has to check if it changed. If you switch to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush then components only check if their inputs have changed. https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more on what an iterator is. An array is an iterator, but it is implicit, automatic, you don't see it. What you count there is not how many times the thing was iterated, but rather, **how many times your function is called**.

If you wanna keep track of how many *iterations* you've had, you have to build a custom iterator. An iterator needs to return a `next()` method that is called as many times as you have values to return. What you return from this `next()` is an object with `{ value, done }` signature - `value` being whatever and `done` is true when you are done. It is inside this `next` that you can count number of iterations.

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iterator-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts) an example next to your code.

What a JavaScript engine does, is it makes arrays iterables implicitly.